# How many replica set members consitute majority in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB 3.2 manual is not very clear as to what constitutes a majority with regards to write concerns in a replica set e.g. w="majority". It is somewhat subjective.

In a replica set of 10 members anywhere from 6 to 9 would mean a majority to me.

But from what I can gather it is not just a majority, it is the minimum number required to be defined as a majority. So in a set of 7 that would be 4, for 12 that'd be 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The write concern of [**`majority`** is well defined](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/#writeconcern."majority"):

> Requests acknowledgment that write operations have propagated to the majority of voting nodes, including the primary, and have been written to the on-disk journal for these nodes.
>
> […]
>
> with w: "majority", the primary also writes to the on-disk journal before acknowledging the write.

So this write concern will be acknowledged *as soon as* the majority of voting members has done the write. Given your example of a 7 member replica set, you are right assuming a majority of 4.

There is a caveat on using **`majority`**, however. If you have more voting members than data bearing nodes, say 6 data bearing nodes and an arbiter, and 3 of those data bearing nodes fail, the replica set is still fully functional for both reads and writes. However, to satisfy a write concern of majority, the write would need to be acknowledged by 4 data bearing nodes, which is impossible with just 3 data bearing nodes still up. So a write concern of **`majority`** should be considered carefully when having more voting members than data bearing nodes.

Comment: Oh yea, I understand the risk of using w=majority, I just wasn't sure what does majority meant in this context. Thanks